# Read text from a file to use variables in a bash script

Tags: bash

i've got a text file with configuration in that I want to parse into a script. Any idea how I do this?

config;

```
name = joe
age = 38
location = oxford
```

For example, i'll ask the question to the user;

```
Would you like to get the user details? [Y/N]:
```

Then after the user says yes it will parse this config into the commands i'm building.

Comment: What did you try for yourself? Did you look at similar questions before?

Comment: *to parse into a script* - how should look the final result?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suggest you to use the cut command, here is the manual : https://linux.die.net/man/1/cut

And here is an example for your case :

```
cut -d'=' -f1 /path/file
cut -d'=' -f2 /path/file
```

Comment: Thank you, that article helped solve my problem